# Динамическое создание массивов

Tags: java, рефлексия

Написал функции для создания и инициализации одномерного массива и матрицы. Как в main вывести оба массива в консоль?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array.*;
public class ArrC {

  public static Object arrC (Class cls, int size){
    size = 5;
    Object arr = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(cls, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (cls.isPrimitive()){
            java.lang.reflect.Array.set(arr, i, 2);
        }
    }
     return arr;
}

public static Object matrixC(Class cls, int row, int col){
    row = 7;
    col = 5;
    Object matrix = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(cls,  row, col);
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(row); i++ ){
        for (int j = 0; j < Array.getLength(col); j++){
            if (cls.isPrimitive()){ 
                java.lang.reflect.Array.set(matrix, i, 7);
                java.lang.reflect.Array.set(matrix, j, 5);
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
public static void main (String[] args){
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
    s.append(arrC(ArrC.class ,5));
    System.out.print(s);
    s1.append(matrixC(ArrC.class , 7, 5));
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Для массивов существует метод Arrays.toString(arr)
В методе matrixC у Вас была ошибка: вместо Array.getLength(row) Array.getLength(col) используйте просто row и col

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrC {

  public static Object arrC (Class cls, int size){
    size = 5;
    Object arr = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(cls, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      if (cls.isPrimitive()){
        java.lang.reflect.Array.set(arr, i, 2);
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }

  public static Object matrixC(Class cls, int row, int col){
    row = 7;
    col = 5;
    Object matrix = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(cls,  row, col);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++ ){
      for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
        if (cls.isPrimitive()){
          java.lang.reflect.Array.set(matrix, i, 7);
          java.lang.reflect.Array.set(matrix, j, 5);
        }
      }
    }
    return matrix;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args){
    String s = Arrays.toString((int[])arrC(int.class ,5));
System.out.println(s);s.toString());
    System.out.println();
    StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
    ArrC[][] arrCs = ((ArrC[][])matrixC(ArrC.class, 7, 5));
    for (ArrC[] arrC1 : arrCs) {
      s1.append(Arrays.toString(arrC1))
        .append("\n");
    }
    System.out.println(s1);
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, опять выручили ;)

Comment: PS В соседнем вопросе увидел про такой метод как Arrays.deepToString(). Его можно использовать для вывода второго метода, вместо цикла: String s1 = Arrays.deepToString(((ArrC[][])matrixC(ArrC.class, 7, 5)));
    System.out.println(s1);